# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when posting to local API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my first time building an API and I seem to be having an issue with post/put requests. Get works as expected. When I try to POST to the api I get and error that says

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Object.addUser (D:\github\DC-API\models\user.js:11:58)

Here is my code.

user.js

```
var db = require('../dbconnection');

var User = {  
  getAllUsers: function(callback) {  
    return db.query("select * from users", callback);  
  },  
  getUserById: function(id, callback) {  
    return db.query("select * from users where Id=?", [id], callback);
  },  
  addUser: function(User, callback) {  
    return db.query("Insert into users values(?,?,?)", [User.id, User.username, User.avatar], callback);  
  },  
  deleteUser: function(id, callback) {  
    return db.query("delete from users where Id=?", [id], callback);  
  },  
  updateUser: function(id, User, callback) {  
    return db.query("update users set username=?,avatar=? where Id=?", [User.username, User.avatar, id], callback);  
  }  
};  
module.exports = User;
```

users.js

```
var express = require('express');  
var router = express.Router();  
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/:id?', function(req, res, next) {  
  if (req.params.id) {  
    User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err, rows) {  
      if (err) {  
        res.json(err);  
      } else {  
        res.json(rows);  
      }  
    });  
  } else {  
    User.getAllUsers(function(err, rows) {  
      if (err) {  
        res.json(err);  
      } else {  
        res.json(rows);  
      }  
    });  
  }  
});  
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  User.addUser(req.body, function(err, count) {  
    if (err) {  
      res.json(err);  
    } else {  
      res.json(req.body); //or return count for 1 & 0  
    }  
  });  
});  
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {  
  User.deleteUser(req.params.id, function(err, count) {  
    if (err) {  
      res.json(err);  
    } else {  
      res.json(count);  
    }  
  });  
});  
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {  
  User.updateUser(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, rows) {  
    if (err) {  
      res.json(err);  
    } else {  
      res.json(rows);  
    }  
  });  
});  
module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var cors=require('cors');
var Users=require('./routes/users');

app.use(cors());
app.use('/users',usersRouter);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am using Postman to test the api and I am sending data through the body with both form-data and raw json. Like I said before this is the first time I am building an API so it could very well be a simple oversight. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `req.body` is undefined whenever you pass it to `User.createUser`. In turn, your `User` parameter in `createUser` is undefined as well, so whenever you try to access `id` inside of the `User` parameter, you get the error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` as you cannot access object properties on undefined values.

To fix this issue, add this to the your app config:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Also, to avoid type collision, I suggest making all of your `User` parameters all lowercase (`user`).

Once you change your parameters to `user` from `User` and add the app config above, your application should work properly.

---

**Edit:** By make all of your `User` parameters lowercase, I only mean function parameters. Here's an example:

```
 addUser: function(User, callback) {  
   return db.query("Insert into users values(?,?,?)", [User.id, User.username, User.avatar], callback);  
 }
```

To this:

```
 addUser: function(user, callback) {  
   return db.query("Insert into users values(?,?,?)", [user.id, user.username, user.avatar], callback);  
 }
```